# Google CalDAV: access to shared calendars

Tags: google-calendar-api

Suppose I have been granted access to some other user's calendar. I can successfully view that calendar in the Google Calendar web UI under "Other Calendars".

Can that calendar be accessed via CalDAV? If so, how?

My CalDAV client starts looking at https://apidata.googleusercontent.com/caldav/v2 and authenticates via OAuth2. It follows the current-user-principal URL and from there to the calendar-home-set. In the calendar-home-set resource collection are the main calendar of the user and some virtual calendars (birthday/anniversaries of contacts, public holidays) but not the shared calendar.

Answer (score 8):

You need to go to the syncselect page and choose the calendars you want synced through CalDAV: https://www.google.com/calendar/syncselect

Comment: Nice. Shared your answer on a [related Thunderbird bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1735525#c3) how to get shared Google Calendars into TB. Seems to be a kinda hidden and not very broadly known setting.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have only read access to the calendar, and you should be able to access it directly via a GET with the URL found under "Other Calendars-> CALNAME -> Calendar Settings" click on the ICAL button (it contains the URL).

The URL will probably be something like: https://www.google.com/calendar/ical/foo.bar.com.calendar.google.com/public/basic.ics

If you are actually asking whether those calendars show up in the CalDAV "collection" of calendars, then I believe (without 100% certainty) that the answer is: No, they do not.